# Using antd Tooltip within antd Form + ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, antd

I need to use antd Tooltip to show "Invalid Email!!",if I enter an invalid mail id.
How to use it in ReactJS antd Form?
The code I am using right now is:

```
<div style={{'height': '40px','display':'flex'}}> 
                      <label style={{'width':'80px','paddingTop':'8px'}}>Main Email:</label>       
                            <FormItem >
                            {getFieldDecorator('Email', {
                        initialValue: '',
                        rules: [{
                          type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                        }],
                      })(
                        <Input placeholder="Main Email" style={{'width':'170px'}} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();                                   
                            this.handleChange(0,e, 'Email')}} />
                      )}                       
                    </FormItem>   </div>
```

How to modify this using antd Tooltip for showing the message?

I have tried another code with tooltip. But the issues are

- it is working only when "hover" to the textbox
- Eventhough I enter correct email, the Tooltip remains there

The code is

```
<div style={{'height': '40px','display':'flex'}}>  
                    <label style={{'width':'80px','paddingTop':'8px'}}>CC Email:</label>        
                    <FormItem >
                            {getFieldDecorator('Cc', {
                        initialValue: '',
                        rules: [{
                          type: 'email'
                        },],
                      })(
                        <Tooltip title="The input is not valid Email">
                        <Input placeholder="CC Email" style={{'width':'170px'}} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();                                   
                            this.handleChange(0,e, 'Cc')}} />
                        </Tooltip>
                      )}                       
                    </FormItem>                     
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a minimal reproduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`visible`](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/) property of tooltip as given below:

```
<FormItem>
  {getFieldDecorator("userName", {
    rules: [
      {
        type: "email",
        message: (
          <Tooltip
            visible={true}
            title="The input is not valid Email!"
          />
        )
      }
    ]
  })(
    <Input
      prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
      placeholder="Email"
    />
  )}
</FormItem>
```

I have created a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk2jq37mom).

Comment: Yeah, But I need the tooltip for email
ie, I want to show the tool tip reain in the page until I tpe the correct email
if I enter a@ then tooltip should be shown,
if a tooltip needed
When I completely type a@gmail.com the tooltip should be disabled

Comment: This is the need

Comment: Can you please create the demo code for the case when validation message is shown when clicking the Submit button?
You edited that code demo. Now I can't refer to that.
I need that logic for other page.
@Triyugi Narayan Mani